# php array from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, authentication

I'm using PHP to get a value from MySQL. My table has this form:

```
COL1 = MAIL mail@mail.com
COL2 = NAME myname
```

and I'm getting from the database the row of the user.

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from user where mail = 'telmo@mail.com'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

print_r($row);
```

But my output is very strange, it gives my like a bidimensional array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => mail@mail.com [MAIL] => mail@mail.com [1] => myname [NAME] => myname )
```

I'm learning PHP and I'm wondering if is this supposed to be like this. Because I would want something more like:

```
MAIL => mail@mail.com
NAME => myname
```

Maybe I'm not getting this syntax very well, but this is why I'm looking for help.
Thanks in advance

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1):

From [the manual](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array)

> mysqli_fetch_array() is an extended version of the mysqli_fetch_row() function. **In addition to storing the data in the numeric indices of the result array, the mysqli_fetch_array() function can also store the data in associative indices, using the field names of the result set as keys.**

What you you're really looking for is [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

> Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows.

Answer (score 1):

Either specify MYSQLI_ASSOC after your query, or use mysqli_fetch_assoc. from the manual:

> resulttype This optional parameter is a constant indicating what type
> of array should be produced from the current row data. The possible
> values for this parameter are the constants MYSQLI_ASSOC, MYSQLI_NUM,
> or MYSQLI_BOTH.
>
> By using the MYSQLI_ASSOC constant this function will behave
> identically to the mysqli_fetch_assoc(), while MYSQLI_NUM will behave
> identically to the mysqli_fetch_row() function. The final option
> MYSQLI_BOTH will create a single array with the attributes of both.

Manual: https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array